# afterCreate not working in the code I prepared for discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to prepare a bot for discord using nodejs. What I want to do here is to send a message to discord every time a new data entry is added to my database. For this I am using the afterCreate hook, but this hook is not triggered in any way. Let me share my code;

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
    ]
});

const sequelize = new Sequelize('xx', 'xx', 'xx.', {
    host: 'xx',
    dialect: 'mysql',
});

const Oyuncular = sequelize.define('texts', {
    string: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'texts',
    timestamps: false,
});


Oyuncular.addHook('afterCreate', 'notifyDiscord', async (record, options) => {
    // ...

    console.log('afterCreate hook work');
    console.log('Record:', record);

    if (record.string !== latestRecord) {
        console.log('new:', record.string);
        latestRecord = record.string;

        const embedMessage = {
            color: 0x0099ff,
            title: 'New Text',
            description: `${latestRecord}`,
        };

        const messagePayload = {
            embeds: [embedMessage],
        };

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1106386276778790975');

    } else {
        console.log('no new text');
    }
});

let latestRecord = null;

// Manually fetching records
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM sokaktansesler', { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
    .then((records) => {
        console.log('Manually fetched records:', records);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error while fetching records:', error);
    });
```

here is my sql table:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ftLS.png)

and here is my versions;

```
{
  "name": "dcbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.14.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.1"
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

I tried hooks in different ways but I think I was wrong in all of them, I would like the hook to be used correctly or to be called and defined correctly on the page